# set position of uitableviewcellaccessory

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitableview

By default the UITalbeViewCellAccessory's position is in the middle of the cell off to the right.  I want to shift it 29 pixels on the Y axis (move it down 29 pixels).  How can i do this?  I tried setting the accessoryView's frame but that didn't work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the accessoryView initial frame is affectless, it is changed any time that the cell does a layout, you need to:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.accessoryView.center = CGPointMake($yourX, $yourY);
}
```

This is a simple way to set a **custom position** for the **accessoryView** that is **persisted in any cell status**

Comment: Does not work. override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        accessoryView?.center = CGPoint(x: 515, y: 195)
    }

Answer (score 1):

A trick for UIImageView's as accessoryView (slightly modified, may contain typos):

```
cell.accessoryView = ({UIImageView * imgV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
                    CGRect frame = imgV.frame;
                    frame.size.width = frame.size.width + 10; //Push left by 10
                    imgV.frame = frame;
                    [imgV setContentMode:UIViewContentModeLeft];
                    imgV; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move the default `UITableViewCellAccessoryType`. You need to just add a custom view to the cell:

```
[cell.contentView addSubview:aView];
```

Answer (score 0):

The default `UITableViewCell` `accessoryView` property is hard-coded proportional using values from the `UITableViewCell` and `UITableView` frame property

(something like `UITableViewCell.accessoryView.frame.x = UITableView.frame.width - *30, and UITableViewCell.accessoryView.frame.y = UITableViewCell.frame.height / 2 - *10)` (*rough estimate values by me)

For example, if you would lower the `UITableView.frame.width` value, the `accessoryView` "absolute" x-position moves to the left, and, similarly, you can adjust the "absolute" y-position by manipulating the `UITableViewCell` height value, and, possibly, you could cascade 2 `UITableViewCell`'s and set the inner one frame height larger than its parent's so that the position of the accessory view (which is positioned to about half the height of the inner `UITableViewCell`) gets a lower "absolute" y-position value.

Not a pretty solution, but that's the one way without custom accessory views.

Answer (score -3):

For that you have to go for `custom accessory view`...because its easier way to change the location of `UITableViewCellAccessory` and for custom accessory view have a look at **[Custom Accessory View For UITableView in iPhone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/impliment-a-custom-accessory-view-for-your-uitableview-in-iphone/)**

Now set the accessories wherever you want.

Good Luck!

Comment: i was afraid you were going to say that.  Any chance you know of an easy way to grab their default images so i dont have to make my own >